# Ant build creates incorrect relative paths to jars when generating manifest

Tags: java, ant, build, classpath, manifest

I'm using Ant to build my Java application and to generate the MANIFEST.MF file automatically so it includes all the jars in my lib directory.

This seems to work but the problem is that instead of writing them as lib/some.jar, it includes my Eclipse project's name: MyProject/lib/some.jar.

This is ofcourse incorrect and causes none of the jars to be found when run as a standalone app.

Build.xml (important part is at the end):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="fidea_migration" default="dist">

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean" description="cleaning the old deliverables">
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="bin" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="_deliverables" includes="**/*"/>
    </delete>
</target>

<target name="prepare" description="preparing the deliverables folders">
    <mkdir dir="_deliverables/lib"/>
</target>

<path id="jarlib">
    <fileset dir="lib/">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile=".">
    <classpath refid="jarlib" />
</manifestclasspath>

<target name="compile" depends="clean, prepare" description="compiling java sources">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <javac srcdir="src/main/java" destdir="bin">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="compile" description="creating binary distribution">
    <copy todir="_deliverables/lib">
        <fileset dir="lib"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="_deliverables">
        <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar jarfile="_deliverables/lib/app.jar" basedir="bin">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.list}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

</project>
```

Example of how my Manifest looks:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Class-Path: MyProject/lib/All-MB.jar MyProject/lib/activation.jar MyProject/lib/aspectjrt.jar
```

Any idea on how to fix this so it just shows xxx.jar instead of MyProject/lib/xxx.jar (so without "MyProject/lib/")?

Cheers,
Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`manifestclasspath` expects the `jarfile` attribute to point to the location of the JAR file (which probably doesn't exist yet, but that's fine).  Since you're creating the JAR file at `_deliverables/lib/app.jar` and you're also copying all the lib JARs from `lib` to `_deliverables/lib` then

```
<manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile="lib/app.jar">
    <classpath refid="jarlib" />
</manifestclasspath>
```

should do the trick, and will create an eventual Class-Path with the right relative paths, i.e. `All-MB.jar activation.jar aspectjrt.jar` etc. etc.

Comment: Had just found out the same thing myself.  Will mark as correct.

Answer (score -1):

You must set your project Dir inside your build.xml as,

```
<property name="projectDir" value=".." />
```

After this, you must try to work on everything with **relative path**. Currently, the reason behind problem is that the *absolute path* is being used.

Comment: Well, I have tried a thousand different ways to try and change it using relative paths but without success.  The problem is always that the manifestclasspath task uses the full paths of the jarlist path.

Comment: Can you please share your whole build.xml? So that I can look more deeper into it